# Is Java Reflection on Inherited Methods Different in Windows and Linux?

Tags: java, windows, linux, reflection

While setting up Hudson for continous integration testing (on a JeOS server), I've come across some strange behaviour I'm hoping the fine people at SO can explain to me.

Our unit tests depend heavily on the use of domain objects, with lots of properties that must be set (due to null constraints in the database). In order to keep our tests readable, we have created a class InstantiationUtils that can instantiate an object and set a series of properties through reflection:

```
public static <T> T newInstance(final Class<T> type, final KeyValuePair<?>... propertyValues) {

    return ReflectionUtils.reflectionOperation(new ReflectionOperation<T>() {

        @Override
        public T perform() throws Exception {

            T object = type.newInstance();
            for (KeyValuePair<?> propertyValue : propertyValues) {

                String propertyName = propertyValue.getKey();
                Object value = propertyValue.getValue();
                String setterName = "set" + StringUtils.capitalize(propertyName);
                ReflectionUtils.invoke(object, setterName, value);
            }
            return object;
        }
    });
}

public static void invoke(final Object target, final String methodName, final Object... params) {

    List<Class<?>> parameterTypes = ListUtils.map(asList(params), "class");
    Class<?> targetClass = target.getClass();
    Method method = MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod(targetClass, methodName,
        parameterTypes.toArray(new Class<?>[] {}));
    invoke(target, method, params);
}

public class Foo {
    private String foo;

    public void setFoo(final String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    private String bar;

    public void setBar(final String bar) {
       this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

The person who wrote this code unfortunately no longer works for us, but as far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with it. Which is also true for Windows - we use InstantiationUtils throughout our unit tests without any problems.

Linux, however, is different. It turns out that in Linux, the newInstance() method only works for direct (i.e. not inherited) members of the class we want to instantiate.

InstantiationUtils.newInstance(Bar.class, "bar", "12345"); will work, while InstantiationUtils.newInstance(Bar.class, "foo", "98765"); will fail on Linux, with the following exception:

> xxx.xxx.xxx.ReflectionUtils$ReflectionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property 'foo' has no setter method

On Windows, both calls will work (I know the newInstance signature doesn't match; we have several overloaded newInstance() methods that convert the parameters to KeyValuePairs).

I had a hard time accepting that inherited public methods are treated differently, so I have tested this in all ways I can think of. And it always ends up with the conclusion that under Linux, at least with the above usage of Reflection, we can't access public inherited methods.

On Windows, I use Sun's JRE 1.6.0.11, in Linux it's also Sun, but version 1.6.0.7.

Can anyone confirm if this is correct? Or is the Reflection usage somehow flawed?

Comment: Are you using the same version of the JRE on both operating systems? That sounds like a much more likely cause of discrepancies than operating system. Also, if you could condense your code into a single complete example it would be easier to verify and explore.

Comment: "Linux, however, is different. It turns out that in Linux, the newInstance() method only works for direct (i.e. not inherited) members of the class we want to instantiate."
23 days early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery partially solved:

MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod() apparently works differently on Linux and Windows.

By using MethodUtils.getAccessibleMethod() instead, it works. Why, I don't know, but I'm guessing that MethodUtils somehow misinterprets the parameter list when figuring out what signature the Method should have.

I'd like to spend more time investigating this, but as always there are things to do and projects to deliver, so I just have to accept that getAccessibleMethod works, and move on :-)

Thanks to everyone for their input!

Answer (score 3):

You are using MethodUtils, and it has some [limitations](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html) :

> Known Limitations
>
> Accessing Public Methods In A Default Access Superclass
>
> There is an issue when invoking public methods contained in a default access superclass. Reflection locates these methods fine and correctly assigns them as public. However, an IllegalAccessException is thrown if the method is invoked.

Another thing to check is if the setFoo() method is overloaded, this may also cause the problem...

Comment: All good points :-) But setFoo() is not overloaded, and all classes in the hierarchy are public.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that the [`SecurityManager`](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-1997/jw-11-hood.html) settings are different between the different Java runtimes?

Certainly I doubt that this is a *platform* issue - it is almost certainly something to do with the JRE version/setup between the two environments

You really need to post the source code to **`MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod`**

Comment: I have thought about that, but usually when there's a SecurityManager issue, I get a very specific exception stating just that. In this case, it's NoSuchMethodException, and no sign of SecurityManager in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try...

On Linux, try comping the code without a reflective call to getFoo() - if it will not compile then reflection has no hope of working (well it does depending on how yoiu setup the CLASSAPTH at runtime...)

Try adding the code below and run it on both Linux and Windows.

```
final Properties properties;

properties = System.getProperties();

for(final Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
}
```

The check the output to make sure that you are using the smae JDK/JRE.  Also check to make sure that the classpath is correct so that you are actually loading what you think you are loading.

Answer (score 0):

Which JVM do you use on Linux, Sun, GCJ etc? If you use something else than Sun's JVM, you could try installing it and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Windows is Sun 1.6.0.11, Linux is Sun 1.6.0.7. I'll try upgrading both to 1.6.0.12 and see what happens.

Comment: Same behaviour with 1.6.0.12, still fails on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have different locales? `StringUtils.capitalize(propertyName)` may be producing different output.

Comment: The locales are actually different. But I tested the output of capitalize(), and it appears to be correct.

Comment: Well, what did you test it on? Admittedly it's unlikely, but there could be a property using a non-ASCII letter with weird capitalization rules, such as the Turkish dotless i

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your `CLASSPATH` ? Are you picking up different versions of the class you want to instantiate depending on which platform you're on ? (e.g. old codebases lying around etc.?)